# Cross tab data control for winform.net 2.0

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0, crosstab

Could anyone suggest me any winforms controls for showing cross tab data in .net?

Updates:
1. The control should be editable
2. Binding support will be add-on feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a read-only display of the data, it might be easiest to use the [ReportViewer control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) with a Matrix.